# Type definition of object literal constant with complex property types

Tags: typescript

I want to have a TypeScript object literal constant with known but long list of properties which all have the same type. Below is the definition of the type and simplified example with only three properties.

```js
type ContainerSize = {
  height: string;
  width: string;
  threshold?: number;
};

const CONTAINER_SIZES = {
  '/': { height: '65px', width: '220px' },
  '/info': { height: '220px', width: '220px' },
  default: { height: '700px', width: '500px', threshold: 480 },
} as const;
```

The issue with the definition above is that the property types are not `ContainerSize`. This can be fixed by using `Record<string, ContainerSize>` as the object type:

```js
const CONTAINER_SIZES: Record<string, ContainerSize> = {
  '/': { height: '65px', width: '220px' },
  '/info': { height: '220px', width: '220px' },
  default: { height: '700px', width: '500px', threshold: 480 },
} as const;
```

but now any string is a valid key and thus `CONTAINER_SIZES['not-existing']` wouldn't show an error.

Is there any other way to define the object literal than writing the properties twice as in the example below?

```js
const CONTAINER_SIZES: Record<'/' | '/info' | 'default', ContainerSize> = {
  '/': { height: '65px', width: '220px' },
  '/info': { height: '220px', width: '220px' },
  default: { height: '700px', width: '500px', threshold: 480 },
} as const;
```

Comment: Why do you want the property values to be `ContainerSize`, specifically? I'm guessing it's for developer experience, but anything specific?

Comment: Yes it's for the developer experience. If some function parameter type is `ContainerSize` it's better if you can see immediately from `CONTAINER_SIZES` that is has the right property types instead of checking if they match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for you:

1. Inferring the keys by defining the object separately first
2. A do-nothing function that returns `ContainerSize`

#### Inferring the keys from previous object

It **must** be possible to do this in a single step, but here's how you can do it with two steps:

```typescript
const _sizes = {
    '/': { height: '65px', width: '220px' },
    '/info': { height: '220px', width: '220px' },
    default: { height: '700px', width: '500px', threshold: 480 },
} as const;
const CONTAINER_SIZES: Record<keyof typeof _sizes, ContainerSize> = _sizes;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJwMqoF7QC8UA3gFBRQAWEqA5lcAFxQDOwm6dA3BVAO6oAJsCot2nBDz6jMEVlTgAbIQH4WCAK4BbAEZZeAX15kAxonZQA+q3zyoxcpQDkAemcsS1Wg2ZRnAGwArGAAHs4ANALCoizOAEzxAAxhzlCGEXxu6ABmcB6k3vSMcYkp4VGCImL+ZanpmZRCEDnImkp+XjTFfs4A7EnlkdHVcUGDqVGy8ooqLAAsABxJDWSGUMisUOYI7Lw7ljAA8gByACoAggCSJwCiAEpW2FcAWrfYLPcQ5phCADwAawgIDgOSgoEgoOstgIrCi8CQaAwODsAD4HNC7KxeEA)

As you pointed out (thanks!), that loses the readonly aspect of the property values (both `CONTAINER_SIZE`'s property values and the values of the `ContainerSize` objects), which we can fix with `Readonly` in two places:

```typescript
const CONTAINER_SIZES: Readonly<Record<keyof typeof _sizes, Readonly<ContainerSize>>> = _sizes;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

#### A do-nothing function

Another option, which I've used when I wanted `ContainerSize` enforced when providing the values (developer experience stuff), is to have a do-nothing function:

```typescript
const cs = (size: ContainerSize) => size;
```

Then:

```typescript
const CONTAINER_SIZES = {
    '/':      cs({ height: '65px', width: '220px' }),
    '/info':  cs({ height: '220px', width: '220px' }),
    default:  cs({ height: '700px', width: '500px', threshold: 480 }),
};
```

That provides autocompletion for property names etc. within the object literals being passed into `cs`. (On one of the projects where I did this, I quickly found that I wanted to add some cross-property verification logic to the function, so it ended up not being a do-nothing in the end...)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJwMqoF7QC8UA3gFBRQAWEqA5lcAFxQDOwm6dA3BVAO6oAJsCot2nBDz6jMEVlTgAbIQH4WCAK4BbAEZZeAX15kAxonZRTrKMQAUrfBBbwkaDDicBKWwD42TibmCJYwAPIAcgAqAIIAkhEAogBKAPrYcQBaidi2pHyUAOQA9IUslBXWdiTUtAzMUIUAbACsYAAehQA0AsKiLIUATIMADB2FUIZeXQWNxegAZnBllFU1NPSMA8NjnT2CImKNO+OT07NCEAvImkoNVqzVtZsNhQDsI7vdvYcDLZ-jHqyeSKFQsAAsAA4RmcZoYoMgbMF2LwgA)

Comment: If this is a common thing to define you could also use function for the inference behavior

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - :-) Great minds think alike, I remembered doing that on a project just after posting and was adding it. Makes for better devex when specifying the values.

Comment: When inferring keys from the previous object the current solution allows modification of the properties (`as const` is not applied to `CONTAINER_SIZES`). Using `Readonly` utility type would fix this discrepancy: `const CONTAINER_SIZES: Readonly<Record<keyof typeof _sizes, ContainerSize>> = _sizes;`

Comment: @SamuliAsmala - Thanks for pointing that out! I think you need the `Readonly` on the property type rather than the object, though: `const CONTAINER_SIZES: Record<keyof typeof _sizes, Readonly<ContainerSize>> = _sizes;` https://tsplay.dev/w6XnYm

Comment: Good point! I missed that property assignment. Actually I think I need the `Readonly` for both the property type and the object https://tsplay.dev/WPxPqW

Comment: @SamuliAsmala - LOL, you are of course, quite correct. :-) I was trying to add a *new* property to `CONTAINER_SIZES`, I missed reassignment.